# Android - EditText on status notification

Tags: android, button, notifications, android-edittext

Does anyone know if I can insert an EditText (for inserting text) on an Android notification? I would like to have a button and an edittext when the button is pressed then get back the text on the edittext.

It's possible? Thanks

Comment: Ortitz were you able to add an EditText?
I get an exception when I try to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in Jelly Bean but as far as I know not in version prior to that. Since this is built in to the android system it should be considered and acceptable practice.

From the android blog:

Bi-directional text support: Android 4.1 helps you to reach more users through support for for bi-directional text in TextView and EditText elements.

[Android blog post that mentions this capability](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/06/introducing-android-41-jelly-bean.html)

Here is were you can learn about "[Creating a Custom Notification Layout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)"

Comment: Edited to add a link to the Android Developer Status Notification page where they discuss custom notification layouts. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

But it was good in case where you are using the pdf reader and at the same time you need to use a dictionary then its good to type a word into the textbox and will get its meaning instead of switching from one app to another.

Comment: The question is closed!

Answer (score -4):

Is that good UI? I don't think people expect to write something on a notification. It'll confuse them. Why don't you just have a button that opens your app and lets the user type?

Comment: Quicker for whom? If users don't expect this, it's going to confuse them. It won't be quicker, and you'll have a lot of strange user questions on your hands.