# Putting notification from xml file

Tags: android, xml, remoteview

I have an xml file defined as follows:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
android:gravity="center"  
android:orientation="horizontal" >  
  <EditText  
  android:id="@+id/view1"  
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
  android:text="notif"  
 />  
 <Button  
  android:id="@+id/button1"  
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
  android:text="Send" />  
</LinearLayout>
```

I am trying to add this xml file to a notification and this is what I have so far:

```
     RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
 R.layout.custom_layout);
 NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
 context).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setContent(
 remoteViews);
 // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app  
 Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, Receiver.class);
 TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
 stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
 PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,
 PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
 remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button1, resultPendingIntent);

 NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
 // mId allows you to update the notification later on.  
 mNotificationManager.notify(100, mBuilder.build());
```

But when I try to add it like this, I get the error "Bad notification posted from package [package name]. Couldn't expand RemoteViews"

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`RemoteView`'s layout does not support `EditText`. Try replacing it with a `TextView`.
You can refer to [this list](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout) for views/layouts supported by `RemoteView`

Hope that helps

Comment: But according to this, it says EditText can be put on the notification panel. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12764281/android-edittext-on-status-notification

Is there something similar to RemoteView perhaps?

Comment: Also anyway I can make a textview editable to get user input?

Comment: Well, the post you refer to mentions it is only possible on Android > 4.1 (API 16). I am still not sure it will work though. And for the making `TextView` editable - no, it won't work.