# Android notification with text inbox on it

Tags: android, notifications, textinput, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I need to add text inbox in to android notification bar.I know that jelly bean support for expanding the android notification bar.http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

So anyone know is it possible to add text inbox in android notification bar.

Sajith

Comment: what do you mean by "text inbox"?

Comment: means android edit text for reading text input

Comment: you cannot put an edit text in a notification

Comment: is that the reason os not support or other thing.ok what are the capabilities have in jelly bean for android notification bar.

Comment: In here it says possible.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12764281/android-edittext-on-status-notification

Comment: Read the link you posted it tells you the capabilities of a notification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear, but if you mean to ask,.....
how to put out an alert like dialogue ....

First : create an XML layout with just a Textview width and height. =matchparent

Then in the manifest put this. "android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog ""

Finally in your activity refer to this XML

Comment: That's not what is being asked.